# Qt Animate QPushButton Icon

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qpushbutton, qicon

I would like to animate the size of the QPushButton icon, because when i try to animate whole QPushButton object size, icon is not resizing at all. It seems theres no property "setScaledContents" on QPushButton icon. I tried to use this code for icon in my custom QPushButton method (on hover):

```
QIcon *icon = new QIcon(this->icon());
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation((QObject*)icon, "size");
animation->setDuration(1000);
QSize test = this->size();
animation->setStartValue(test);

animation->setEndValue(QSize(test.width()+100,test.height()+100));

animation->start();
```

But i receive an error "segmentation failed" on this code. Is there any other way i can animate my QPushButton icon?

Comment: `QIcon` doesn't inherit from `QObject`, so this type cast: `(QObject*)icon` is dangerous and wrong.

Comment: QPushButton has iconSize property. Why not animate it instead of animating QIcon?

Comment: I tried   `QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "iconSize");
    animation->setDuration(500);
   // QSize test = this->size();
    animation->setStartValue(QSize(1024,1024));

    animation->setEndValue(QSize(512,512));

    animation->start(); ` but it doesn't work

Comment: Changing to "iconSize" worked for me just fine... I did not bother subclassing QPushButton and I made sure to assign an icon to QPushButton (arbitrary PNG).  Try it out with just "size" first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is instead pass in a valid reference to a [QObject (per Chris' comment above)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html#QPropertyAnimation-2)

Your code works fine if I simply replace the parameter passed into QPropertyAnimation:

```
// ui->pushButton is a QPushButton*
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton, "size");
animation->setDuration(1000);
QSize test = this->size();
animation->setStartValue(test);
animation->setEndValue(QSize(test.width()+100,test.height()+100));
animation->start();
```

I'm going to assume that you're subclass-ing QPushButton (explains this->icon())... perhaps you can try to access it directly instead?  Though I'm going to guess that it's privately owned by the base/parent class.

Comment: Hello, yes im subclassing the QPushButton but im doing this to get the acces to hover property

Comment: I already tried to animate QPushButton itself but the icon doesn't resize with it. (no scaled contents property). I need a slow animation effect of changing size on image itself.